# Symfony4 Form Validation in Bootstrap Modal

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I have two forms in my controller

```
public function index($id, Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
{
    $user = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(User::class)
        ->find($id);

    // First form for edit User //
    $form = $this->createForm(EditUserType::class, $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $user = $form->getData();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getManager();

        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();
        $this->addFlash('notice', 'User profile has been updated');
        return $this->redirectToRoute('user_list');
    }

    // Second form for edit password //
    $form2 = $this->createForm(ChangePasswordType::class, $user);
    $form2->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form2->isSubmitted() && $form2->isValid()) {

        $user->setPassword(
            $passwordEncoder->encodePassword(
                $user,
                $form2->get('password')->getData()
            )
        );

        $user = $form2->getData();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getManager();

        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();
        $this->addFlash('notice', 'User password has been updated');
        return $this->redirectToRoute('edit_user', [
            'id' => $id
        ]);
    }

    return $this->render('desktop/editUser.twig', [
        'formPassword' => $form2->createView(),
        'form' => $form->createView(),

    ]);
}
```

I pass it to view:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 mx-auto">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary content-margin-top-bot password-button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> Password change </button>
            <h2>Edit user</h2>
            {{ form_start(form)}}
            {{ form_widget(form)}}
            {{ form_end(form)}}
        </div>
</div>

<div class="row justify-content-center ">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div class="modal" id="myModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">

                    <!-- Modal Header -->
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Change password</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data 
 dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Modal body -->
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        {{ form_start(formPassword) }}
                        {{ form_widget(formPassword)}}
                        {{ form_end(formPassword) }}
                    </div>

                    <!-- Modal footer -->
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data- 
 dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my ChangePasswordType:

```
class ChangePasswordType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('password', RepeatedType::class, [
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank(),
                ],
                'type' => PasswordType::class,
                'required' => true,
                'first_options' => ['label' => 'New password'],
                'second_options' => ['label' => 'Repeat password', ],
                'invalid_message' => 'Passwords must be identical',
            ])
            ->add('change password', SubmitType::class);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And my question is, this form isn't validated properly, when I open form in modal I can edit password but there is no validation if I put 2 different passwords, modal is closed and looks like password has been modified but it isn't. Only when I open modal form again I get the info 'Passwords must be identical'. How should I validate this form properly?

Answer (score 0):

You should add some additional code to your javascript, because the modal wont be open again, if you submit this form and it is not valid.

Quick and dirty solution for this is to place the following code.

```
{% if not formPassword.vars.valid %}
    $('#idofyourmodal').modal('show');
{% endif % }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! This code in Twig works fine and i will try to do it in nicer way in my js file

Comment: I'll promise, you'll not found another way, because of the basic problem, that your javascript file doesnt know anything about the valid status of the form. Whatever you do, you'll have to pass that {{ formPassword.vars.valid }} status to your script. You can pass some custom variables to the twig (check the validity of the form inside the controller between submitted() and valid()) but in view of basics, thats the same.